# Occasional Out of memory building a trie in Android

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

One of the first things my app does is read in a text file full of words and build a trie out of it.  Testing on an older phone, a Droid X with 512MB RAM, It sometimes crashes with "Out of memory on a 160-byte allocation" while it is building the trie.

Weirdly, it doesn't crash every time.  Using an 80K wordlist, it crashes every other time it's launched.  With a list of 20K words, it crashes every fourth time the app is launched.  I don't understand what's going on that would affect the memory allocation across multiple launches, but it is very predictable.

Is there anything I can do to free up or pre-allocate memory so that it will work every time?

It's possible I'm doing something dumb/wasteful building the trie, so I'll post the relevant bits.  Here's the part that reads the file and adds to the trie:

```
public void LoadText(Activity a) {
    InputStream is = a.getResources().openRawResource(dictfile); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String readLine = null;
    int wordsadded = 0, timeslogged = 0;
    try {
        while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            trie.insert(readLine.toUpperCase(Locale.US));
        }
        is.close();
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here's the trie's insert method:

```
protected void insert(String word) {
    int n = word.charAt(0) - 'A';
    if (c[n] == null)
        c[n] = new TrieNode();
    if (word.length() == 1) {
        c[n].end = true;
    } else {
        c[n].insert(word.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'across multiple launches'? From the behaviour you've described, it sounds like you're simply hitting the Home key and then re-entering the app - which probably won't remove it from memory, and it sounds like you're re-building the trie each time (perhaps from an `onResume` or `onStart` somewhere?). Could you describe the steps you take to launch the app multiple times?

Comment: I'm exiting the application with Back, then re-launching it by tapping the icon.  If I get out of the app using Home and then re-launch it, you're right, it just brings the still-running app back to the forefront.

Comment: To clarify, the app does occasionally fail on launch in other situations - this is just how I've gotten it to happen reliably.  My guess was that the periodic failures have something to do with how much memory Android is using for other background activities, and that it could be solved by forcing Android to free up enough memory for it.

Comment: Are you storing this data in a singleton somewhere? You can check running processes in the DDMS view in Eclipse; if you're storing this data somewhere outside the scope of the Activity that's creating it, then even though the Activity is killed, the data lives on with the app process. Certainly that's what appears to be happening.

Comment: Have checked with some apps I've got here that store data in a custom `Application` class - the process persists even when I exit with the Back button, and though the `Activity` is recreated, the old data is still present in the `Application` class.

Comment: The trie is contained in a class called "Dict", which is just a regular member of the Activity.  As in, "Dict dict; dict = new Dict();"  I thought that it would either persist in memory (and not be recreated) or get destroyed and gc'd when the app exited.

Comment: That's what I would expect would happen too. Unless something else is holding onto a reference to it somewhere, I'm out of ideas sorry!

Comment: No, my app's single activity contains everything, so I don't think anything could have a reference to it.  Thanks anyway.